# How to modify text description returned at the Python prompt?

Tags: python

At the Python shell, whenever we enter a bare bound name we get back some text describing the object it (the name) is bound to:

```
>>> class c:
...  pass
...
>>> o = c()
>>> o
<__main__.c object at 0x00510B30>
>>>
```

Is this text like an official attribute of the object, or is it returned by a function? **Can it be changed?**

**Update**: I read the answers below and understand them. But what about when objects of a class each returns a different value, such as strings? There has to be an object-level (not class-level) attribute that's the source of this info.., right?

Comment: `def __repr__(self): return "yes it can"`

Answer (score 2):

This text is returned by the default implementation of `__repr__()` on the class. All you have to do to change it is override the `__repr__()` method.

```
>>> class C:
        def __repr__(self):
            return 'My Message Here'

>>> o = C()
>>> o
My Message Here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can whether use `__str__()` or `__repr__` but the more often used is `__repr__()` because `__str__()` only return when type changed to string type

For example:

```
class MyName():
      def __repr__(self):
          return "Faran2007"
      def __str__(self):
          return "FaranAiki"
```

At Console

```
>>> Obj = MyName()
>>> Obj
Faran2007
>>> Full_name = str(MyName())
>>> Full_name
FaranAiki
```